# Java - NoSuchMethodError on java.io.BufferdReader.lines on other systems

Tags: java, intellij-idea, bufferedreader, jsmooth

I'm using a small "xml text based database" to store information. While coding and debugging I had no problems with a method I created, but as an exe file(wrapped with jsmooth), it gives me an error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.io.BufferedReader.lines()LJava/util/stream/Stream: 
      at primary.loadErrorDB(primary.java:471
```

So i checked line 471 but on Intellij, there is no such error, everything works fine there.

Hope you guys know what to do.

This is the method

```
    public static Object[] loadErrorDB() {

    File db = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\errordb.xml");

    Object[] errordbAry = new String[20][20];

    FileReader file = null;
    try {
        file = new FileReader(db);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);

        Stream<String> streamList = br.lines();

        errordbAry = streamList.toArray();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    String a = "";
    for (Object o : errordbAry) {
        a = a + String.valueOf(o) + ";";
    }

    String[] srgAry = a.split(";");

    String[] newAry = new String[srgAry.length - 5];
    int x = 0;

    for (int i = 5; i < srgAry.length; i++) {
        newAry[x] = srgAry[i];
        x++;
    }

    return newAry;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
br.lines(); <--BufferedReader don't have method lines() upto Java7 use readLine()
```

*Update Java to `Java8` to use this feature.*

If You want to read one line at a time use

```
String line=br.readLine();
```

Before that make sure that file you are trying to read has line by `null` check.

```
String line=null;
if((line=br.readLine())!=null)
  {//Go Ahead
  }
```

See more one this from [`BufferedReader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#lines--

BufferedReader.lines() was added in Java8.  Check the version of Java that is being used after packaging with jsmooth.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.io.BufferedReader` class in upto java 7 has `readLine()` but it dont have the `lines()` [Refer  the method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html). But in java 8 `java.io.BufferedReader` has the lines() [refer for java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)

So first of all check which version of java you have and then proceed accordingly